# Issue with WrapperClass variables

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a wrapper class in my controller and I am trying to assign String to the wrapper variable based on object's field value. How ever, if the field is null, then it is not able to assign the value to the variable as you can see the empty value in the third row.

[image: Page Screenshot]

Class:

```
public void getEngagements(){
 if(wrapList!=null)
 wrapList.clear();
 selectedTrack = '';
 trackOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
 trackOptions.add(new SelectOption('--None--','--None--'));
 Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Learning_Community__c.Track__c.getDescribe();
   List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

   for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)
   {
      trackOptions.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
   }       

    Lcoptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    Lcoptions.add(new SelectOption('','--Unassigned--'));
    for(Learning_Community__c obj :[SELECT Id, Name 
                                    FROM Learning_Community__c 
                                    Where Cohort__c=:selectedCohort  
                                   ])
    {
        Lcoptions.add(new SelectOption(obj.Id,obj.Name));
        lcOptionsMap.put(obj.Id,obj.Name);
        System.debug('lcOptionsMap '+lcOptionsMap);

    }
    integer i=0;
    String s='--None--';
    String s1='--Unassigned--';
    wrapList = new list<WrapperClass>();
    for(Engagement__c eng : [SELECT id, Name, Site__c, Learning_Community__c,Cohort__c,Learning_Community__r.Name, Learning_Community__r.Track__c 
                             FROM Engagement__c 
                             WHERE (Cohort__c=:selectedCohort OR Site__c=:selectedSite) 
                            ])
    {  
        if(eng.Learning_Community__c==null){            
        wrapList.add(new WrapperClass(eng,trackOptions,'--None--',Lcoptions,'--UnAssigned--',i)); 
        System.debug('wrapList '+wrapList);           
        } else{

        wrapList.add(new WrapperClass(eng,trackOptions,eng.Learning_Community__r.Track__c,Lcoptions,eng.Learning_Community__c,i));   
        }

        i++;
    }
```

}
wrapper class:

```
public class WrapperClass{
        public Engagement__c eng {get; set;}
        public List<SelectOption> selectedTrack{get; set;}
        public String selectedNTrack{get; set;}
        public List<SelectOption> selectedCLC{get; set;}
        public String selectedLC{get; set;}
        public integer rowcount{get;set;}
        public WrapperClass(Engagement__c e,List<SelectOption> track, String s,List<SelectOption> clc, String lc, integer r){
            selectedTrack = track;
            eng = e;
            selectedNTrack = s;
            selectedCLC = clc;
            selectedLC = lc;
            rowcount = r;
        }
    }
```

Page Code:

```
<tbody>
   <apex:repeat value="{!wrapList}" var="e">

      <tr>                                                                                                                          
          <td>{!e.eng.name}</td>                                                            
          <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.Learning_Community__r.Name}" id="lc"/></td> 
          <td> 
              <apex:selectList value="{!e.selectedLC}" size="1">                                                                              
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!e.selectedCLC}"/>  
                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!refreshPage}" rerender="lc"> 
                  <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/>                                                                                                                                       
              </apex:actionSupport>
              </apex:selectList>                                                                
          </td>  
          <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.Learning_Community__r.Track__c}" id="track" /></td>  
          <td> 
              <apex:selectList id="trackv" value="{!e.selectedNTrack}" size="1">                                                                           
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!e.selectedTrack}"/>
                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!refreshPage}" rerender="track" > 
                  <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/>
                  </apex:actionSupport>                                                                            
              </apex:selectList>
          </td>                         
      </tr>
   </apex:repeat>                                             
</tbody>
```

Debug Log:

> {Id=a03n0000000q8VGAAY, Name=Scott Nicholas - July 2016,
>   Site__c=ALPHA, Cohort__c=July 2016, RecordTypeId=0125000000054OLAAY},
>   rowcount=2, selectedCLC=(already output), **selectedLC=--UnAssigned--,
>   selectedNTrack=--None--**, selectedTrack=(already output)])

Expected Result:
[image]

Comment: Is the problem the lack of Select options in the New LC and New Track selects?

Comment: I guess the problem is Learning_Community__c's value is actually '' or some other blank string. Can you add a System.debug for this and let me know the value of that field in that record?

Comment: @LanceShi: Thanks for the reply: Added debug log as you requested for that record only.

Comment: @DanielBallinger: Thanks for reply: Options are available in the Select Options. and I am trying to populate "--Unassigned--" and "--None--" if the object LC is null.

Comment: So which are the fields that are not assigning well in your code. I find it hard to map your columns to your code without page code information

Comment: What's the actual problem here?  What should it be doing?  At the moment you've just described what your system is currently doing.

Comment: @LanceShi : The page code is attached. I am doing the below logic: if(eng.Learning_Community__c==null){            
            wrapList.add(new WrapperClass(eng,trackOptions,'--None--',Lcoptions,'--Unassigned--',i));            
            } else{

            wrapList.add(new WrapperClass(eng,trackOptions,eng.Learning_Community__r.Track__c,Lcoptions,eng.Learning_Community__c,i));   
            }
the else part is working. If the eng.learning_community__c==null, then assign the '--None--' and '--Unassigned--' values to the wrapperclass variables. But, it is not assigning.

Comment: @NickCook: If the eng.learning_community__c==null, then assign the '--None--' and '--Unassigned--' values to the wrapperclass variables. But, it is not assigning. WrapperClass variables are : "selectedLC" and "selectedNTrack". For other 3 rows, engLearning_community has value so, it is populating.

Comment: @Ajay  What is supposed to be doing the assigning? Where are you trying to populate these values?  On the page?  In the controller when the user clicks submit?  In the database?  Can you provide a screenshot of what it should look like?  You really need to be more clear.

Comment: @NickCook: I have added the screenshot for expected output. When I click on the "Go" button I am populating the table with wrapperlist. I am also updated the "Go" method in the above description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your apex variable assigning. It is what you expect on your page is not what you wrote in your controller.

Under your learning community, it is referring to e.eng.Learning_Community__r.name which is absolutely null when Learning_Community__c is null.

To fix your issue. Just fix your page:

```
<tr>                                                                                                                          
          <td>{!e.eng.name}</td>                                                            
          <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.selectedLC}" id="lc"/></td> 
          <td> 
              <apex:selectList value="{!e.selectedLC}" size="1">                                                                              
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!e.selectedCLC}"/>  
                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!refreshPage}" rerender="lc"> 
                      <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/>                                                                                                                                       
                  </apex:actionSupport>
              </apex:selectList>                                                                
          </td>  
          <td><apex:outputText value="{!e.selectedNTrack}" id="track" /></td>  
          <td> 
              <apex:selectList id="trackv" value="{!e.selectedNTrack}" size="1">                                                                           
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!e.selectedTrack}"/>
                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!refreshPage}" rerender="track" > 
                  <apex:param value="{!e.rowcount}" assignTo="{!count}" name="count"/>
                  </apex:actionSupport>                                                                            
              </apex:selectList>
          </td>                         
      </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked perfectly fine. Regards, Ajay. Thanks NickCook

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 blank columns use the follow variables from the wrapper:

- e.eng.Learning_Community__r.Name
- e.eng.Learning_Community__r.Track__c

as evidenced by the VF code you've supplied:

- `<td><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.Learning_Community__r.Name}" id="lc"/></td>`
- `<td><apex:outputText value="{!e.eng.Learning_Community__r.Track__c}" id="track" /></td>`

These are not text fields, so when Learning_Community__c is null, they will not have any values and will always be blank.

If you really need these columns to show a '--none--' value when the LC field is blank, you'll need to reference a text field in the wrapper, not the field on the LC object.

Comment: These are String fields in wrapper class as I have described above. public String selectedNTrack{get; set;}
                public String selectedLC{get; set;}

Comment: @Ajay No they're not.  The 2nd and 4th columns are referencing an sobject field. `selectedNTrack` and `selectedLC` are being used to assign the select option values to, in the 3rd and 5th columns